# CD to MP3 converter with full control over filenames and folders

Tags: mp3, music-management, audio-conversion

I'm looking for a good CD to MP3 converter (doesn't have to be free) that gives full control over the names of the mp3s in terms of any combination of - artist, track number, track name, album name - any spaces, dashes or characters I would like to add.

Also full control of the directory structure that is created from the disk - artist\album name, album name\artist etc...

Also, the program should be able to access the internet to CDDB sources

MusicMatch had all these, but alas they where bought by Yahoo and discontinued circa 2007-8

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to beat the versatility, options, and quality of [EAC](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/) combined with [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/). It won't be the most user friendly option, but this combination gives total control over every aspect of taking a CD to MP3, bitrates, filenames, ID3 tagging, etc.

If you go this route, [Hydrogen Audio](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/) has a good wiki and forum for easier configuration of the two combined.

EAC can pull CD metadata from CDDB, although lately I will just rip, encode, and finish the fine tuning of filenames and tags via [mp3tag](http://mp3tag.de/en/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

[Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) is the one I always recommend. When you rip you get this dialog:

[image: Media Monkey Set Destination Wizard]

which lets you configure the main directory, how (any) subdirectories and the file names are built from the track details. You can choose from the following when you click on either of the ">>" buttons:

[image: Filename selections]

Comment: +1 I haven't looked back since I started using MediaMonkey.  The paid version doesn't have the limitations of the free version and was well worth the price (a lifetime license was actually pretty cheap.) It's also great when you have a large collection of mp3s (I've ripped almost all my CDs, so it's huge.)

Answer (score 2):

One really excellent tool, which comes recommended by the creators of the great CD Burner XP creators, is Foobar 2000 (I use it to backup my music CDs):

CDBurnerXP - Save an audio CD to disk (includes instructions)
  http://cdburnerxp.se/help/Audio/ripaudiodisc

Foobar2000 (can also automatically figure out proper track names in most cases)
  http://www.foobar2000.org/